# Slide in UITableViewCells while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and would like to animate rows that will appear again. I also want to switch between animations, some cells should get `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft` and others `UITableViewRowAnimationRight`. But I don't know how to implement this feature with my `UITableViewController`. I tried to insert following lines of code into `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *updatePath = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:updatePath 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Instead of sliding in the cell, the order of the cells changed or some of them appeared twice. I also tried to insert these lines after cell creation.

```
if (cell == nil) {
...
} else {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSArray *updatePath = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:updatePath 
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you're going to have success reloading rows once the table has started the process of displaying the cell on screen. `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` typically results in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called, so I'm surprised you're not getting into an infinite loop. Instead it appears, the table is getting into a bad state.

My recommendation would be to do your own animation in this case, manipulating the cell's transform property in `willDisplayCell`. You can do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (<should animate cell>) {
        CGFloat direction = <animate from right> ? 1 : -1;
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(cell.bounds.size.width * direction, 0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }
}
```

You'll need to provide logic for "should animate cell" - you probably don't want to animate cells on initial load.

Comment: Thx in advance. I'm going to try your solution. I don't think it would be bad to implement this feature, when initializing the first rows. But would it be a problem at initial load, if I do it this way?

Comment: It just depends on how you want it to look.

Comment: It is a chat and the rows (with the messages) should be animated from left or right, depending on who wrote the message.

Comment: what value should I pass here <animate from right> and <should animate cell> ,